# How can I do networkx animation for stored frames?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, networkx

I want to color my graph based on a metric that I have **already generated**  and stored. These would be my frames [each frame of length = number of nodes of the graph] for a matplotlib animation that should be passed to the node_color attribute of the graph. How do I turn this into an animation? Here is a minimum non-working example for a small graph:

```
# number of nodes
size = 10.

# generate graph
G=nx.complete_graph(size)

# generating input frames here, since my data is too big
# its important that the frames go as input and is not generated 
# on the fly
frame = np.random.random_integers(0, 5, (size, size)) # random ndarray between 0 and 5, length and number of frames = number of nodes in the graph

# draw the topology of the graph, what changes during animation
# is just the color
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos)
edges = nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos)
plt.axis('off')

# pass frames to funcanimation via update function
# this is where I get stuck, since I cannot break
# out of the loop, neither can I read every array of
# the ndarray without looping over it explicitly
def update(i):
    for i in range(len(frame)):
        # instead of giving frame as input, if I randomly generate it, then it works
        nc =   frame[i] # np.random.randint(2, size=200)
        nodes.set_array(nc)
    return nodes,

# output animation; its important I save it 
ani = FuncAnimation(fig8, update, interval=50,  blit=True)
ani.save('crap.gif', writer='imagemagick',  savefig_kwargs={'facecolor':'white'}, fps=1)
```

Because of the stated problem, the animation ends up showing just the last frame or just the first frame.

Note that if I use nx.draw() inside the update function, I get the following error: RuntimeError: The animation function must return a sequence of Artist objects.

I have a strong feeling I am missing something obvious easy way out here and that this problem is trivial. But since I do not use animation function frequently, I can't quite catch it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nearly there: `update` just wants the status at time t. If I read your code correctly, you are looping over all `t` within `update`. So just get rid off that loop and add the `frames` paramter to `FuncAnimation` so it knows which times to check.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

# number of nodes
size = 10

# generate graph
G=nx.complete_graph(size)

# generating input frames here, since my data is too big
# its important that the frames go as input and is not generated
# on the fly
frame = np.random.random_integers(0, 5, (size, size)) # random ndarray between 0 and 5, length and number of frames = number of nodes in the graph

# draw the topology of the graph, what changes during animation
# is just the color
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos)
edges = nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos)
plt.axis('off')

# pass frames to funcanimation via update function
# this is where I get stuck, since I cannot break
# out of the loop, neither can I read every array of
# the ndarray without looping over it explicitly
def update(i):
    # for i in range(len(frame)):
    # instead of giving frame as input, if I randomly generate it, then it works
    nc = frame[i] # np.random.randint(2, size=200)
    nodes.set_array(nc)
    return nodes,

# output animation; its important I save it
fig = plt.gcf()
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=50, frames=range(size), blit=True)
ani.save('crap.gif', writer='imagemagick',  savefig_kwargs={'facecolor':'white'}, fps=1)
```

[image]

Comment: networkx just uses matplotlib as its drawing "backend". I am not 100% sure what the issue is but if you look into matplotlib colormaps you will probably figure it out. If negative values are being capped at 0, a quick fix would be to offset `frame` by its minimum: `frame -= frame.min()`.